# Permission denied to upload folder Django

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to upload images in django. I have set static directory in settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/assets/image/')
MEDIA_URL='http://127.0.0.1:8000/assets/image/'
```

here is my model image Field

```
doImage=models.ImageField(upload_to='doImage/%Y/%m/%d',verbose_name='Do Image')
```

Now when i tried to upload it then i faced permission denied 13 error.
I had tried command **chmod** with 777 to give a permissions to folder

```
sudo chmod -R 777 assets
```

i also had tried change user of file using command

```
sudo chown -R hassan:hassan assets
```

But both things didn't worked for me. So anyone have idea that what's going wrong let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django stores files locally using `MEDIA_ROOT` and `MEDIA_URL`. Please refer this [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/files/) for more details.

For example you can also check [this](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/01/how-to-upload-files-with-django.html).

Comment: Please check i had added media_root and media_url but still its giving me back permission error. t

Comment: Thanks. Its issue with folder. i was using same folder for static assets and media. So i had changed folders that's solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do:
 `sudo chown -R root:root assets`
This way only root user has rights over `assets`

Do:
`sudo chown -R your_user:your_user /path/to/your/assets`